# How to make slf4j print its own configuration?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

log4j has a system property called log4j.debug, that when set by adding -Dlog4j.debug=true to your command line, prints out the information about how log4j configures itself (for example, the location of the con file it found and loaded).

I am looking for a similar capability for slf4j. Can we tell slf4j to print out how it is set and configured?

Answer (score 0):

slf4j is wrapper for other loggin systems (the f in the name stands for facade), it does not have its own configuration.

With slf4j you can even use log4j as real logging library. If you are using logback as logging library along with slf4j there is an attribute debug for the main configuration tag (if you are using an xml file for configuring logback).

```
<configuration debug="true"> 
....your conf here
</configuration>
```

the logback mnanual can be found [here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/index.html)